# WAS 7.0 Create users and map role to users wtih wsadmin

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I have a requirement to create userids and assign Admin role for some users and I am trying to do this through a Jython script as it will speed up the process and saves time.
So,I have created the below Jython script to achieve it.

**Script**

```
import sys


filename="C:\Users\harish\Desktop\scripts\input.txt"
fileread = open(filename, 'r')

filelines = fileread.readlines()  

for row in filelines:  
   column=row.strip().split(';')
   user_name=column[0]
   print user_name  
   pass_word=column[1]  
   first=column[2]  
   last=column[3]  
   AdminTask.createUser(['-uid',user_name, '-password', pass_word, '-confirmPassword', pass_word, '-  cn', first, '-sn', last ])

   AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole(['-roleName','Administrator','-userids',user_name])

   AdminConfig.save()

   print 'Userid creation completed for', user_name

fileread.close()
```

The script runs fine and doesn't throw any errors.However, the users are not able to login to WAS Admin Console and they can only able to do it after I save the configuration by clicking "OK" at page "Users and Groups" -> "Administrative User Roles" ->

Can someone please let me know what am I missing here while working with wsadmin or is  there anything else I need to do to accomplish the task ?

I am working on WAS 8.5.5.0 version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the script give you the output that it has in fact performed the actions in the script?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add this code to the end of your script (not in the for-loop). This will refresh the security configuration.

```
agmBean = AdminControl.queryNames('type=AuthorizationGroupManager,process=dmgr,*')
AdminControl.invoke(agmBean, 'refreshAll')
```

This assumes you're using Network Deployment, `process=dmgr`. You may need to change the process.